# How can I insert a new row by writing a query in SQL Server in my own format?

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to execute a query to insert rows in to a table in SQL Server. As, its simple it is working fine and insert a row for `datetime` column in `yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss` `ttt` format. My problem is I have to insert the row in `dd/MMM/yyyy` `hh:mm:ss ttt` format. Is it possible to do this through a query in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It also is a sensless attempt. WHY do you want to introduce some culture specific date coding into your database access coding?

> yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss ttt format

This is the ISO culture independant format that works regardless of what the user's computer is set to. It is there for a reason.

> My Problem is i have to insert the row in dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss ttt format

No, you do not. You just are under the illusion. You ahve to insert a date time into sql server. NOTHING says you can not format it properly first.

Why do you HAVE to insert it in this particular specific format?

Comment: My, application has Some criteria to insert in that format. And we can adjust with ISO culture independant format also but i am just trying it out, whether we can do it or not.

Comment: No, your application pretty surely has no criteria that the SQL scripts look like that. Whatever users enter should te parsed and putin to proper date time variable types, with sql generated out of those (or: parameters for the parameterized sql statement generated out of those). I am VERY sure there is no criteria of using a particular formatting on the sql layer.

Comment: If there is such a criteria it must be because other parts of the site/application picks the server date string directly and do no convert, and that is plain stupid coding then and should be replaced as fast as possible as it will continue to cause untold problems for the future.

Answer (score 1):

That should work fine, especially as the month component is MMM not MM (which can cause conversion problems).

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know SQL server stores the date time in the same format internally, no matter what you give it. parsing the string to a datetime is another matter.
to use different formats you can use the CONVERT function and provide the style argument,
i think 113/13 is closest to what you specified